# combine associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
<?php
$arrayName1 = array(
    '0' => array('name' => 'steve' ,'age' =>51 ) , 
    '1' => array('name' => 'john' ,'age' =>48 ) , 
);

$arrayName2 = array(
    '0' => array('name' => 'Steve' ,'place' =>'downtown' ), 
    '1' => array('name' => 'John' ,'place' =>'New York' ), 
);

$output = array(
    '0' => array('name' => 'steve' ,'age' =>51, 'place' =>'downtown'  ), 
    '1' => array('name' => 'john' ,'age' =>48 ,'place' =>'New York' ), 
);
```

Looking forward to combine two arrays wrt the "name" key, and obtain the sample  result as $output. **array_merge**() isn't working as expected.

Comment: Do the same names always occur at the same indexes?

Comment: I am no specialist, but this operation is a merge... did you check the array_merge function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: What does `array_merge` return and how are you invoking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no guarantee that the same names will occur at the same indexes in the two arrays, you need to search for the matching `name` value in `$arrayName2` and then merge the values from that entry into the value from `$arrayName1`:

```
$names2 = array_map('strtolower', array_column($arrayName2, 'name'));
$output = array();
foreach ($arrayName1 as $array) {
    $key = array_search($array['name'], $names2);
    if ($key !== false) {
        $output[] = $array + $arrayName2[$key];
    }
    else {
        $output[] = $array;
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => steve
            [age] => 51
            [place] => downtown
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => john
            [age] => 48
            [place] => New York
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/m9M7d)

Comment: Can i use this code to combine 3 arrays... the third array contains the keys-name and email ID. Thanks

Comment: @steve sure - I'd change it slightly to make it more efficient for multiple arrays. See for example: https://3v4l.org/mRM4t

Answer (score 1):

use `array_replace_recursive`

```
$arrayName1 = array(
        '0' => array('name' => 'steve' ,'age' =>51 ) , 
        '1' => array('name' => 'john' ,'age' =>48 ) , 
    );

$arrayName2 = array(
    '0' => array('name' => 'steve' ,'place' =>'downtown' ), 
    '1' => array('name' => 'john' ,'place' =>'New York' ), 
);

$out = array_replace_recursive($arrayName1, $arrayName2);
print_r($out);
```

**Output will be**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => steve
            [age] => 51
            [place] => downtown
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => john
            [age] => 48
            [place] => New York
        )

)
```

Comment: This will only work if  the same names always occur at the same indexes.

Comment: @Nick yes, as per question details i suggested that. Thanks.

Comment: The question actually says "combine two arrays wrt the "name" key", which does not imply the same name always occurs at the same index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function combine_array($array1,$array2,$combineProp){

foreach($array1 as $item){
    $combinedKey = strtolower($item[$combineProp]);
    $combinedArr1[$combinedKey] =  $item;
}

foreach($array2 as $key => $item){
    unset($item[$combineProp]);
    $combinedKey = strtolower($array2[$key][$combineProp]);
    $combinedArr2[$combinedKey] =  $item;

}

foreach($combinedArr1 as $key => $item){
    $combinedItem = $item;
    if($combinedArr2[$key]){
       $combinedItem = array_merge($item,$combinedArr2[$key]);
    }
    $resultArr[] =  $combinedItem;
}

return $resultArr;

}
 $output = combine_array($arrayName1,$arrayName2,'name');
```